# How to add class in c#(server) to ListView li item

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Linq in server I fill my list like this

```
selected MenuId=3;     
ul_HeaderMenu.DataSource = data.TABLE_MENUS.ToList();
ul_HeaderMenu.DataBind();
```

this client code

```
<asp:ListView ID="ul_HeaderMenu" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ItemTemplate >
        <li class="li-HeaderMenu"  runat="server"  ><%# Eval("Name") %>
             <div class="TopMenuActive"></div>
        </li>
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I need to add class to the li the I building in server some think like this

```
selected MeduId=3;     
ul_HeaderMenu.DataSource = data.TABLE_MENUS.ToList();
ul_HeaderMenu.DataBind();
ul_HeaderMenu.ElementAt[3]AddClass('test');
```

I just find the way to add class to li.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the itemdatabound event on your list

```
<asp:ListView OnItemDataBound="YourListView_ItemDataBound" ID="ul_HeaderMenu" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ItemTemplate >
        <li ID="listItem" class="li-HeaderMenu"  runat="server"  ><%# Eval("Name") %>
             <div class="TopMenuActive"></div>
        </li>
    <ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

then in code behind, something like this;

```
protected void YourListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    HtmlGenericControl myLi = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("listItem");
    myLi.Attributes.Add("class", myLi.Attributes["class"].ToString() + " yournewclass");
}
```

Comment: But how i do this to one specific item  not to all items?

Comment: that depends on the condition, inside the databound event you have access to the item index; e.Item.DataItemIndex

Answer (score 0):

The ListView is comprised of the items which are defined by your ItemTemplate section, and not of the li elements. Therefore, when you get an element from the ListView by index, you would first need to find the li before you can add a class to it.
Therefore, you need to use `FindControl` method on the item to get the li.

Now, there are a few things wrong here.

ListView doesn't have an `ElementAt` method, it's `Items` collection has it, but still, I would use `ul_HeaderMenu.Items[3]` to get an element at an index.

If you want to use `FindControl` method, you need to add an id to your li inside your ItemTemplate which you will pass to FindControl to get the li.

`AddControl` method does not exist, you have to use `Attributes` collection on the li to change the class attribute. Here you have to be careful though since you want to keep the classes already there, so you'll have to concatenate the strings, but you don't want to add a same class multiple times, therefore it's best if you created a helper method AddClass that takes the string and returns it with the class added.

You can do all this at any point, but usually you'll want to use the `ItemDataBound` event, as described by Lars Anundskas in the meantime.

And lastly, while you're free to use any convention you like, personally I find your casing convention confusing - you can read a bit on Microsoft's suggestions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).